# -Woverloaded-virtual warning for const function

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, declaration, gcc-warning

I have this piece of code:

```
class ISerializable
{
        public:
            virtual bool operator==(const ISerializable* /*value*/) const { return false;};
            virtual bool operator!=(const ISerializable* /*value*/) const { return true;};
};

class Point2I : public ISerializable
{
        public:
            bool operator==(const Point2I& value)
            {
                return (x == value.x && y == value.y);
            }

            bool operator!=(const Point2I& value)
            {
                return !(*this == value);
            }
            public:
            int x;
            int y;
};

class Coordinate : public ISerializable
{
         public:
            virtual bool operator==(const Coordinate& value) const;
            virtual bool operator!=(const Coordinate& value) const;
};
```

It is causing me **-Woverloaded-virtual** warning on gcc compiler.

I understand this warning due to that function declaration in **Point2I** hides virtual functions from **ISerializable**.
But I am not sure if just missing **const** in **Point2I** can cause this warning.

Can you please help me understand if it is **const** which is causing this warning or something else? Warning description from gcc didn't mention anything specifically.

**Update:**

I found another class **Coordinate** in my code base which was already overriding this and gcc not throwing warning for this. Only difference in **Point2I** and **Coordinate** is I didn't declare it **virtual with const** in **Point2I**. It appears just **const** is hiding base class declaration.

Comment: Always use `override` keyword, it will generate a compiler error instead of a warning.

Comment: Regarding the updated question: Doesn't any of the answers you've gotten already explain what's happening? `const` or no `const` - you get the warning for overloading a `virtual` method instead of overriding it. I think both answers explained that and I think I explained how you can actually `override` the `virtual` method too.

Answer (score 3):

> if it is const which is causing this warning or something else?

I'd say that it's *something else*, namely that you are not actually overriding the base class methods, even if you add `const`.

The argument `const ISerializable*` is not the same as `const Point2I&`.

---

One solution could be to override the base class methods, using `const ISerializable&` as the argument, and cast in the overridden methods:

```
class ISerializable {
public:
    // add virtual destructor if you need to delete objects through
    // base class pointers later:
    virtual ~ISerializable() = default;
    virtual bool operator==(const ISerializable&) const { return false; }
    virtual bool operator!=(const ISerializable&) const { return true; }
};

class Point2I : public ISerializable {
public:
    bool operator==(const ISerializable& value) const override {        
        auto rhs = dynamic_cast<const Point2I*>(&value);
        // rhs will be nullptr if the cast above fails
        return rhs && (x == rhs->x && y == rhs->y);
    }

    bool operator!=(const ISerializable& value) const override {
        return !(*this == value);
    }

private:
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
};
```

Example usage:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo : public ISerializable {   // another ISerializable 
public:
};

int main() {
    Point2I a, b;
    std::cout << (a == b) << '\n';  // true  - using Point2I::operator==

    Foo f;
    std::cout << (a == f) << '\n';  // false - using Point2I::operator==
    std::cout << (f == a) << '\n';  // false - using ISerializable::operator==

    // this makes the default implementation in ISerializable utterly confusing:
    std::cout << (f == f) << '\n';  // false - using ISerializable::operator==
}
```

---

Another possible solution could be using [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) but this would not work if you want to compare different types derived from `ISerializable<T>`:

```
template<class T>
class ISerializable {
public:
    virtual ~ISerializable() = default;
    virtual bool operator==(const T&) const = 0;
    virtual bool operator!=(const T&) const = 0;
};

class Point2I : public ISerializable<Point2I> {
public:
    bool operator==(const Point2I& value) const override {
        return (x == value.x && y == value.y);
    }

    bool operator!=(const Point2I& value) const override {
        return !(*this == value);
    }

public:
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems.

The first one is different types of parameters

In these functions the parameters have the pointer type `const ISerializable*`

```
virtual bool operator==(const ISerializable* /*value*/) const { return false;};
virtual bool operator!=(const ISerializable* /*value*/) const { return true;};
```

and in these functions the parameters have the referenced type `const Point2I&`

```
bool operator==(const Point2I& value)
{
    return (x == value.x && y == value.y);
}

bool operator!=(const Point2I& value)
{
    return !(*this == value);
}
```

The second one is that the first functions are constant member functions while the second functions are not constant member functions.